# Issue with Google Analytics API advanced segment

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When I enter in my segment ID in the Google analytics API and run the report, the following error comes up: 'User does not have sufficient permissions for this advanced segment.' I have no idea why this is happening I am logged in and have allowed the API permission to my sheets.